# Android HttpClient logging in without entering credentials

Tags: java, android, http, httpclient

I am using a httpclient to communicate with my server and after the login is authorized, I clear the text area but when I come back to the LoginActivity and click login (username and password textbox are set to empty), it successfully logs in with the previous credentials.
I have no idea why it logs in without entering the credentials.

I am using a public static httpclient across my app.

Thanks

Code

```
     private void login(){
    try {

        httppost = new HttpPost(Server_path);
        nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username",username.getText().toString().trim()));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",password.getText().toString().trim()));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        final String response = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);

        dialog.dismiss();

        if(response.contains("Welcome")){
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Login Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    username.setText("");
                    password.setText("");

                }
            });
            //setMessage();
            startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
        }else{

            showAlert();

        }

    }catch(Exception e){
        dialog.dismiss();
        System.out.println("Exception : " + e.getMessage());
    }

    }
```

Comment: Is server accepting empty username and password?

Comment: Debugging the application would surely help you understand why and how it is happening. Use some breakpoints, watchpoints, on the client as well as on the serever.